# В каком случае не получится построить декартово дерево?

Tags: алгоритм

Вообщем, надеюсь, вам знакома такая структура данных, как декартово дерево.

Я строю декартово дерево. С клавиатуры вводят два числа: a(i) и b(i) по a[i] - дерево поиска, по b[i] - минимальная куча. Причем все a[i] различны , и все b[i] различны.

Теперь вопрос: в каком случае я не смогу построить декартово дерево?

(Мне кажется это можно всегда, автор задачи утверждает обратное.)

Пример декартового дерева:

```
               (10;40)
              /       \
          (8;15)      (40;35)
         /     \      /      \
     (7;13)  (9;12) (37;33)  (42;34)
```

[Задача №2781. Декартово дерево](http://informatics.mccme.ru/moodle/mod/statements/view.php?id=1974#1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы говорите про вот [**эту задачу,**](http://informatics.mccme.ru/moodle/mod/statements/view.php?id=1974#1) то да, декартово дерево по заданным кортежам `{A, B}` можно построить всегда.

Неявный смысл задачи как раз в том, чтобы *реализовать построение этого самого дерева* по заданным данным, а не в том, что для каких-то случаев это невозможно.

Если в какой-то момент вам захочется подсмотреть в готовое решение, то можете глянуть [**сюда.**](https://gist.github.com/1491556)

Comment: похоже вы правы, и проблема в реализации , спасибо!